# Having trouble putting together Image Sitemap XSD according google specs

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I currently have a sitemap configuration for our website, however I'm trying to add the images according google sitemap specification.

Here's how it looks like today:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/category/something</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/category/something2</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

And how it should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url> 
</urlset>
```

According to google's documentation (https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/) I need to use the core sitemap for the core elements (the one I'm still using) and use a the image one for image elements.

That's the tricky part for me - it looks very simple to do it, but I'm not that skilled to achieve that.

I managed to do that in my XSD file (I'm using jabx plugin):

```xml
<xsd:schema
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
        targetNamespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" schemaLocation="image.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="urlset">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="url" type="tUrl" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="tUrl">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="loc" type="tLoc"/>
            <xsd:element name="lastmod" type="tLastmod" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="changefreq" type="tChangeFreq" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="priority" type="tPriority" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="image:image"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

<!-- and goes on -->
```

This makes it work, but it scrambles the namespaces - the image elements don't have the namespace image, and the core elements receive a random namespace **ns2**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <ns2:url>
        <ns2:loc>https://www.example.com/</ns2:loc>
        <ns2:changefreq>daily</ns2:changefreq>
        <ns2:priority>0.7</ns2:priority>
    </ns2:url>
    <ns2:url>
        <ns2:loc>https://www.example.com/category/example1</ns2:loc>
        <ns2:changefreq>daily</ns2:changefreq>
        <ns2:priority>0.7</ns2:priority>
        <image>
            <loc>https://www.example.com/images/ẗest.jpg</loc>
            <caption>test</caption>
            <title>test</title>
        </image>
        <image>
            <loc>https://www.example.com/images/ẗest2.jpg</loc>
            <caption>test2</caption>
            <title>test2</title>
        </image>
    </ns2:url>
</ns2:urlset>
```

I'm running out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: XML namespaces are not difficult if you learn one very important fact. The prefix is _not_ the namespace. So 'ns2' is not a 'random namespace'. It is just a shorthand for a perfectly normal namespace. Take a couple of online tutorials and it will all become clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there was another way of doing this, but I fixed the prefix by creating a namespace mapper:

```java
public class DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

    private Map<String, String> namespaceMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Create mappings.
     */
    public DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper() {
        namespaceMap.put("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", "");
        namespaceMap.put("http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1", "image");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        return namespaceMap.getOrDefault(namespaceUri, suggestion);
    }
}
```

And when using the marshaller, I simply set:

```java
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper mapper = new DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper();
m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper);
```

My XML looks correct exactly the same way as google documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Add second XmlNs in XmlScheme, namespaceURI is mapped with nameSpace in XmlElement, i think this is causing lot of confusion, add namespace in XmlElement to match prefix you want.